# Scala 2.13, SBT: sbt compile uses wrong compiler version

Tags: scala, sbt

I am porting a small legacy library from scala 2.12 to scala 2.13. sbt version is 1.3.3. The project is flat and relatively simple. *scalaVersion* declared in the project is 2.13.1.

I am executing *clean* and *compile* tasks, and then publish to both local *ivy* and to the artifactory.
The process seemingly goes fine and creates the artifact with the *_2.13* suffix. When this binary gets executed against scala 2.13 runtime, it fails with *MethodNotFound* exception. Further introspection shows that the artifact was compiled for 2.12 but not for 2.13.

Does anybody have an idea why a different compiler version was used by sbt, and how to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you reloaded your SBT session after the change?

Comment: Please, post the relevant parts of your `build.sbt`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yes, J jumped through different hoops multiple times, including wiping out all possible caches like ivy directory and Coursier cache and reloading.

Comment: @laughedelic *build.sbt* is trivial. The only relevant part is the scala version declaration: *scalaVersion := "2.13.1"* . The rest is the project descriptor, library dependencies and artifactory resolvers.

Comment: I think there's just not enough information to be able to help you. If the build configuration is trivial as you say, you can create an example project (or describe it in the question) so that people can reproduce it and try to solve. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @laughedelic Yes, I agree. This is actually what I was planning to do. But there is still an outstanding question if that makes sense: what else can possibly define the compiler version besides the `scalaVersion` SBT setting?

Comment: There's `crossScalaVersions` (see cross-building sbt docs), there is a default Scala version set in sbt which will be used if your build configuration fails to set it right (could be about scoping).

Answer (score 0):

Just had similar issue, sbt was compiling my project to the wrong Scala version, found this question without answers in google.

So, my problem was actually very simple. Turns out you need to start sbt in a project root directory (where build.sbt is located). I was running it from a directory where all my .scala files were located, so it haven't parsed build.sbt and compiled project using default Scala version (2.12 in my case).

Comment: Thank you, Victor, I always run sbt from the project root, but I will soon check it again.